# How to save the markers that I can clear them?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I load some markers from server using volley.

I can ad new markers on the map but the problem if i delete some markers from database, they will not deleted from the Map.

So how can I save all markers that I can use clear() to delete  them from the map before loading them from server ?

```
ArrayList<MapsActivity_listitem> MyMarkers = new ArrayList<MapsActivity_listitem>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue;




requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("mymarkers");



                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                int id = Integer.parseInt(respons.getString("id"));
                - - -

MyMarkers.add(new MapsActivity_listitem(id, name, lat, lon));


                            }





                            JSONObject respons2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String id = respons2.getString("id");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        for (int i = 0; i < MyMarkers.size(); i++) {
                            createMarker(MyMarkers.get(i).getId(), MyMarkers.get(i).getLat(), MyMarkers.get(i).getLon());
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


    }
```

Comment: does `createMarker` return a marker object?

Comment: no, it does not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to clear all the markers on the map you can call [the clear method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear()) of the GoogleMap object

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

private void removeAllMarkers(){
    mMap.clear()
}
```

If you also want to track all your markewrs and be able to clear your items you should store em in some kind of list like an HashMap, then loop through it and remove each marker from the map like this:

```
private Map<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();

private void removeAllMarkers(){
    Iterator it = mMarkers.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        ((Marker)pair.getValue()).remove();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: thamks, I have just added **mMap.clear()** before  **createMarker ...** then it works fine.